# Is it a good design to return value by parameter?

Tags: c++, api

```
bool is_something_ok(int param,SomeStruct* p)
{
    bool is_ok = false;

    // check if is_ok

    if(is_ok)
       // set p to some valid value
    else
       // set p to NULL
    return is_ok;
}
```

this function return true and set p to a valid value if "something is ok"
otherwise return false and set p to NULL

**Is that a good or bad design?** personally, i feel uncomfortable when i use it.
If there is no document and comment, i really don know how to use it.

BTW:Is there some authoritative book/article about API design?

Comment: Note that the function cannot possibly set the pointer to NULL. A copy of the pointer is passed as parameter, and even if that copy is made null, the calling code will not notice. If you want to fiddle with the pointer you need an extra level of indirection (call it pointer or reference:  `bool op( int, SomeStruct *& )` or `bool op( int, SomeStruct ** )` and then things get a little nastier.

Comment: You might want to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/2139254#2139254

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question as C++ and not C, I would suggest you to:

- return the value directly
- if you have more than one value, use output parameters
- use non-const references as output parameter where possible (instead of pointers), and use const-references for the input parameters.
- if something went wrong, raise a exception instead of returning false or -1.

But that are just some general hints. The best way to go always depends on the specific problem...

Comment: What is the best practice if you have only one return value? Then return it directly I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you want to handle 'errors'.

For example, take the standard function atoi.  It converts a string to an integer, but if the string does not contain a number, what should it return?  In this case, the C/C++ runtime will set the errno global variable.  An alternative would be to throw an exception.

Personally, I don't really like both of these alternatives.
Therefore, if I generally use the following rules:

- Is there a value in the range of possible return values that can be used to indicate an error, and do I only have 1 possible 'kind of' error?  In those cases, I use the return value to indicate the error.  E.g. a function like FindEmployee could simply return NULL if the employee is not found.
- If all possible values could be returned by the function (as in the atoi example), use an output argument for the return value, and let the function return a boolean.  If you have more than 1 possible error case, return an enum that indicates the kind of error (or success) that occurred.

Comment: The third option (which is used in QT) is passing an error return variable as argument (`int QString::toInt( bool* error=0, int base=0 )`). +1 for bringing other error mechanisms into discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to do this. 
The alternative in your example is to either encode two things into one return value (For example using NULL as a special value) or to return a structure.

Encoding two things can sometimes be impossible, and is a little error prone. Returning a structure is a lot of extra work and clutter. So I tend to do what you've done. I tend to assume that "raw" pointers and references in a parameter list are for returning values in, and they would be "const" if they were only for passing data in.

But to be honest I forget that rule as often as I remember it so perhaps it's not a very good one.

There is a class "optional" in the boost library which might fit your needs but I never really liked it myself for perhaps no very good reason.

Comment: +1 for bringing optional into the discussion. Little fancy utility that is almost always forgotten...

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends. How expensive is your type to copy construct? Can you write your function [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)-friendly? At least until we have C++0x with [rvalue references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Rvalue_reference_and_move_semantics), my recommendation would be not to return "expensive" types (such as `std::vector<std::string>`), but rather pass them as references, e.g. use:

```
void split(const std::string &txt, char sep, std::vector<std::string> &out);
```

rather than:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &txt, char sep);
```

Depending on how you write your function it's possible that RVO will kick in but in my experience it's not something you can generally rely on.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question for a book about API design. Look for "API Design for C++" by Martin Reddy, which was published in 2011.

As a comment to the accepted answer. In the book the author actually suggests to prefer const references for input parameters and pointers for output parameters since it indicates the client more explicitly that the parameter may be modified, e.g. foo(bar) vs. foo(&bar).

Also you can watch the talk [How To Design A Good API and Why it Matters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw). Which uses mainly Java however as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

I think to return NULL if something is not OK and valid SomeStruct if OK is better in this case

```
SomeStruct* is_something_ok(int param);
```

In this case except of checking boolean value you should check is it NULL, and if not use it.

But there is cases when you have to return value by parameter. It depends from the number of return values, and the context function can be used.

Comment: But sometimes NULL *is* a valid return value.

Comment: @Matthew In that case you would define a particular implementation of your class to be representative of a null value.  Then the calling code can handle both situations indifferently.

Comment: Which make the design more complicated, If you are working in a team it may be better to keep things simple.

Comment: In cases when NULL is valid value, or return type can't be NULL Microsoft choose return value as parameter in .Net framework, for example methods TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
bool is_something_ok(int param,SomeStruct* p);
```

or

```
// return NULL if the operation failed.
Somestruct* do_work(int param);
```

It is hard to say if a design/API is good or bad, nothing is black or white ... (grey?!?!?)

You must choose the API/Standard which will be **easier for you to code** with. And **be coherent**, if you choose the first method type, do it for the rest of your project.

Dont also forget **to document your code**, so It will be more easier to understand how to use your API.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to return the the Result-Type directly like so:

```
SomeStruct doSomething(int param) {...}
```

and throw an exception in cases that the function can't handle (tux21b already mentioned this way). Alternatively you can return two types with `std::pair` without throwing an exception like so:

```
pair<SomeStruct, bool> doSomething(int param) {...}
```

And third i like to declare output parameters as pointers instead of references (like you mentioned) because in the calling code i see the difference of input and output parameters. Given the function:

```
void doSomething(const Somestruct& in, Somestruct* out) {...}
```

Then in the calling code it is visible (without looking at the function declaration) what's the input and what's the output parameter (if i consecently apply this concept).

```
SomeStruct a;
SomeStruct b;
doSomething(a, &b); // you see a is input, b is output
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) when you want to return a value only on success.